# links to related tags

Tags: feature-request

It would be nice if given a tag one could find related tags (either subfields, superfields, or intersecting fields), especially if one needs to search for an appropriate tag from a large list. Thus it should be possible to define links in a related-graph, and be able to follow these.

Comment: There has been considerable discussion of these types of structures on the mother meta over time (and this is certainly a discussion that belongs on the mother meta as it would possibly affect all sites). Until recently they were firmly shot down, but that position may be softening. I'll try to find a link.

Comment: Here's the recent thread that looked promising to me: [A real solution to ambiguous tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125234/2509). On another look it doesn't address the whole "sub-tag" or "tag-tree" issue at all, but could provide the infrastructure that would make such a thing viable.

Comment: I have been ammoyed with the tag system and had a similar proposal, but I thought that it would require nontrivial changes to the system. After looking at the other MSO question, it seems the proposal has a chance. So I proposed a more definite version there http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126092/tag-suggestions-related-tags